# How to set asp.net mvc routing for deployment in windows azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, azure-connect

I am working on Asp.net mvc 4. I am trying to deploy my project on windows azure as a webrole. I have made caustom routes in global.asax(i.e. RouteConfig.cs) file like,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultConn",
                url: "{id1}/{id2}",
                defaults: new { controller = "mycontrollername", action = "actionname", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It actually works in local environment. But when i publish my website into windows azure environment it shows **404 Page Not Found Page**.

I have accessed the page with the following url,

```
http://xxx.cloudapp.net/mmdg/kli
```

It gives 404 page not found exception. so please guide me.